# Android telephony app that requres callers to press a number before my phone rings

Tags: android, phone, spam

I've been getting a lot of robocalls lately, and am looking at alternate ways to block them.

What I'm looking for is an Android app that will answer my calls for me and require that the caller press a specific number or series of numbers. Only if the caller presses the correct numbers will my physical phone ring. For example,

> Thank you for calling. Due to large robocall volumes, please enter 4-2-9-# on your keypad to speak to me. Thank you.

I know that there are a fair number of apps that block calls based on blacklists and/or heuristics, but that's not what I'm talking about. I want everyone, from the lowliest Medicare benefits scammer to the President of the United States, to have to press a number to make my phone ring.

Criteria:

- Runs on Android 10.
- It's acceptable if the software uses my phone "minutes" to answer calls.
- Not an app that blocks based on a blacklist or heuristics.
- Does not require me to switch to a specific phone plan or phone company.
- May have an initial or ongoing cost as long as such cost is competitive with heuristics-based call blockers such as RoboKiller.
- It's a plus if I can choose/rotate the number that callers are required to enter.

The process I'm imagining is somewhat similar to those automated call systems you encounter at many businesses nowadays, where you are asked to press 1 for sales, 2 for support, 3 for prestidigitation, etc., and nobody's phone actually rings in the real world until you press such number.

Comment: Most likely it'll annoy legitimate callers.

Comment: @Alejandro so what? "Doesn't annoy legitimate callers" is not part of my criteria.

Comment: I would bet that the robos could be programmed to provide the response you are asking for in order to proceed to a call to you.  I was getting up to 50 scammer calls per day until I changed my landline number.  Some of the robos I listened to were sophisticated enough to provide off-beat answers that I posed to them.  Thus, I would be skeptical about this working effectively for very long